# Extract Numbers from Array

Tags: php, arrays

How to extract only Numbers from an Array?

```
$myarray = array("A","B", "2","D");
```

I want to get numeric values ("2" in this example) from an array to a variable

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also - what do you mean by *extract "2"*, do you want to remove it, search for it?

Comment: No I want to get numeric values from an array to a varible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [is-numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (PHP build-in functions):

```
$myarray = array("A", "B", "2", "D", "3");
$b = array_filter($myarray, "is_numeric");
```

Now `$b` is an array containing the strings: `2` and `3`.

**Edited** Regarding your comment: if you have only 1 value and you want to add `10` to it you can do:

```
$myarray = array("A", "B", "2", "D");
$b = array_filter($myarray, "is_numeric");
$c = array_values($b); //reset the keys
$finalvalue = $c[0] + 10; // will output 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. let's say I only Have one numeric value. Now I want to take that value and add 10 to it.  I tried $finalvalue = $b+ 10;  but It's not working

Comment: thanx for the update but it returned me error "Undefined offset: 0"  I'm using php 7.2

Comment: @APPBird sorry - needed reset the keys with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: thanx this is Perfect

Comment: Alternatively (and a bit more concisely), `$finalvalue = reset($myarray) + 10;`

Comment: @Progrock Unless you're using functions such as `next`/`key`/etc. (which almost no one uses in 2018 really), there shouldn't be any impactful side effect. You can also use `current($array)` if you want to make 100% sure there are no side effects.

Comment: My original intention was just extract the int values using `array_filter` and `is_numeric`. I add the `array_values` and index 0 at the OP request. Solving it with `foreach` is obvious solution - I was try to use php build-in to avoid writing their code...

Comment: @Progrock "Either way fails or is misleading if there is no numeric present." <- you use it after filtering of course (should've said `reset($b)` earlier, my bad). Also, I meant old-style iterators, obviously. Traditional loop structures such as `foreach` don't alter an array's internal pointers (they use a copy) since PHP7 at least.

Comment: @DavidWinder your original answer was bang on target regarding the original question.  My answer is a reflection of the goal posts changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input  = array('A','B', '2.2','D');

foreach($input as $v)
    is_numeric($v) && $nums[] = $v;

// Take the first numeric found and add 10.
$result = isset($nums[0]) ? $nums[0] + 10 : null;

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
float(12.2)
```